# Tight bounds for $\Phi_n(b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, approximation, cyclotomic-polynomials

> What are tight bounds for $$\Phi_n(b)$$ where $\ \Phi_n()\ $ denotes the $\ n $-th cyclotomic polynomial , $\ n\ge 3\ $ and $\ b\ $ is a "large" positive integer ?

We can assume that the prime factorization of $\ n\ $ is known and hence $\ \varphi(n)\ $. $$b^{\varphi(n)}$$ is the obvious approximation and seems to be already quite good , in particular if $\ n\ $ is large as well. But this approximation can be too small or too big, I guess depending on $\ n\ $, but I could not find out yet how. Any reference or ideas?

Comment: Undoubtedly you know that the next term is $\mu(n) b^{n-1}$. So a lower degree error term only when $n$ is divisible by a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this document titled [The cyclotomic polynomials - Notes by G.J.O. Jameson](https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/%7Ejameson/cyp.pdf), we have from page $2$, section **1.2** *(v)*, the following proposition:

> For all $n \geq 3$, and for all $b > 0$, we have
> $$(b - 1)^{\varphi(n)} < \Phi_n(b) < (b + 1)^{\varphi(n)}.$$

I am not too sure, though, if these bounds are *tight* for large $b$, as I have just commenced my self-study of cyclotomic polynomials.